# Looking for help simplifying a general purpose compression function

Tags: python, file-system, compression, file-structure

The following is a general purpose file compression function with the following features:

1. It can take either a single file or directory as the source input
2. It defaults to the source directory when to destination is input
3. It will compress all files of a type associated with the extension parameter
4. It removes the original files if desired

This allows for a simple minimum working input of providing only the source directory (for which it defaults to compressing all containing files) While allowing specific destinations, individual files, or specific file extensions to be compressed.

```
import glob
import zipfile
import os

def _zip_and_delete_prot(src, dst = None, arcname = None, remove_uncompressed = True, extension = ""):
    """Takes either an individual or list of filenames from the source (src)
    folder and compresses them into the destination (dst) with the option to
    delete the original.

    Parameters:
        src: the path to the source directory
        sdt: the path to the destination directory. If left empty 
                    it will default to the directory of the source files
        arcname: the name of the compressed file (and file path) must correspond
                    to the number of files grabbed from the source
        remove_uncompressed: if True deletes the original input files
        extension: The extension of the batch of files you want compressed 
                    in the source directory, examples are ".txt", ".csv", ".xls"
    """
    # Checks if a destination other than the source is provided, if not defaults to src
    if dst is None:
        if os.path.isdir(src) is True:
            dst = src
        else:
            dst = os.path.dirname(src)

    # Checks if the src is a file or a directory, if a directory we then group all files
    # with the extension given by the extension parameter.
    if os.path.isdir(src) is True:
        fnames = sorted(glob.glob(src + f'\*{extension}'))
    else:
        fnames = [src]

    # Iterating over all files and compressing them
    for _file in fnames:
        # Creating a variable with the .zip filename extension
        file_bn_zip = os.path.basename(_file)[:-3]+"zip"
        zip_dst = dst + "\\" + file_bn_zip

        # Create a Zip file in write mode
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_dst, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zipf:

            # Write to archive without directory structure included in the compression
            if arcname is None:
                zipf.write(_file, arcname = os.path.basename(_file))
                print(f"File {os.path.basename(_file)} written to {file_bn_zip}")

            # If arcname is provided try to use the provided arcname
            else:
                try:
                    zipf.write(_file, arcname)
                    print(f"Arcname {arcname} supplied and compressed")
                except:
                    print(f"Arcnane {arcname} failed, check that structure 
                          corresponds to the src files structure")

            # Removing uncompressed files if desired
            if remove_uncompressed is True:
                    os.remove(_file)
                    print(f"Input file {os.path.basename(_file)} removed")
```

Comment: The title should be the name/purpose of the program only, not the help request. It's understood that every question on the site is asking for code simplification. Consider also fixing your function indentation and showing how it's called.

Comment: @Reinderien perhaps you already saw but in case not - three `import` statements were added in revision 3.

Comment: Your function does not have a Single Responsibility — separate the glob logic, from src vs. dst, from compressing file with explicit src + dst paths. Oddly, you marked it _private. Prefer Path over os. path.* functions. That _file identifier is bizarre, as it is  already a local identifier. Recommend you read PEP-8’s section on choosing names for identifiers. Consider editing / refactoring the current source code, so reviewers can focus on more substantive issues.

Comment: @J_H, I'm struggling to parse your first set of recommendations

1.) "separate the glob logic, from src vs. dst, from compressing file with explicit src + dst paths." Are these three separate issues, or a single issue? Why would I separate the glob logic from the source directory?

2.) I'll do some reading about Path vs os.path (as I have no idea what that is atm)
3.) I'll go over the PEP-8 section and try cleaning it up.

Comment: For (1.) I'm saying that you wrote a single function which does three things. It could call out to three simple helper functions, each of which is [responsible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) for one thing: A.) turn a glob pattern into a sequence of fully-qualified src pathnames of interest, B.) map src pathnames into (src, dst) pathname pairs, C.) compress a src file to produce a compressed dst file. The trouble with your original specification is we cannot write a single simple English sentence which describes the One Thing the function does. So delegate.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is essentially what I was trying to figure out, the function is not easy to read or understand exactly what it does. I like the functionality, but it is cluttered, and the functionality is not conveyed in visual order. I think I should probably use decorators to handle the desired default functionality instead of having all the conditionals cluttering the base function itself. I'll do a full refactor sometime in the next couple days.

Comment: I discourage you from using @decorators. They have their place, but it's not obvious to me that _this_ is a good place for them. (IDK, I could be wrong, maybe there's a good idea lurking in there.) OTOH, a [fluent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#Python) Public API would be one (of serveral) nice ways to deal with orthogonal concerns of "caller cares about SRC directory, but only the *.txt in there", "that filesystem is nearly full, so DST directory should be /var/tmp", "OK, ready to pull the trigger, let's do it, compress those files". Maybe it's `class CompressionSources:`

Comment: The big distinction I wanted to draw was: Identifying and iterating over (src, dst) pathname pairs, is quite separate from compressing src to dst and optionally deleting src upon successful completion. (I _do_ feel the optional deletion is part of the compression operation, and is tightly coupled because it's critical to observe successful status before deleting.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `os` module import with `pathlib` and use more `Path`.

Add PEP484 types to your function signatures.

`sdt` is spelled `dst` in your parameters.

Raw concatenation of an extension string to a glob pattern is asking for trouble; call `escape()` on it.

Re. `# Create a Zip file in write mode` - never

```py
# Do thing
do_thing()
```

Obvious comments are more harmful than having no comment at all.

Don't `is True`; use boolean variables as predicates directly.

### Suggested

Only lightly tested -

```py
import glob
import zipfile
from pathlib import Path


def _zip_and_delete_prot(
    src: Path,
    dst: Path | None = None,
    arcname: str | None = None,
    remove_uncompressed: bool = True,
    extension: str = '',
) -> None:
    """Takes either an individual or list of filenames from the source (src)
    folder and compresses them into the destination (dst) with the option to
    delete the original.

    Parameters:
        src: the path to the source directory
        dst: the path to the destination directory. If left empty
                    it will default to the directory of the source files
        arcname: the name of the compressed file (and file path) must correspond
                    to the number of files grabbed from the source
        remove_uncompressed: if True deletes the original input files
        extension: The extension of the batch of files you want compressed
                    in the source directory, examples are '.txt', '.csv', '.xls'
    """
    # Checks if a destination other than the source is provided, if not defaults to src
    if dst is None:
        if src.is_dir():
            dst = src
        else:
            dst = src.parent

    # Checks if the src is a file or a directory, if a directory we then group all files
    # with the extension given by the extension parameter.
    if src.is_dir():
        fnames = sorted(src.glob('*' + glob.escape(extension)))
    else:
        fnames = src,

    # Iterating over all files and compressing them
    for file in fnames:
        file_bn_zip = file.with_suffix('.zip')
        zip_dst = dst / file_bn_zip.name

        # Write to archive without directory structure included in the compression
        # If arcname is provided try to use the provided arcname
        if arcname is None:
            arcname_inner = file.name
        else:
            arcname_inner = arcname

        with zipfile.ZipFile(file=zip_dst, mode='w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zipf:
            try:
                zipf.write(filename=file, arcname=arcname_inner)
                print(f'File {arcname_inner} written to {zip_dst}')
            except IOError:
                print(f'File {arcname_inner} failed; check that structure '
                      'corresponds to the src files structure')

            if remove_uncompressed:
                file.unlink()
                print(f'Input file {file.name} removed')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for giving an example. I only discovered the PEP484 signatures a couple days ago and seeing how you formatted the parameters was incredibly informative.

Comment: Also the general formatting and use of methods was very helpful